# Join Table with separate id

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, join

In my spring boot application i have the following sample schema consisting of two tables and a join table with an IdClass:

Company.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANY")
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @JoinTable(name = "COMPANY_2_LOCATIONS", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "LOCATION_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
    private List<Location> locations;
    ...

}
```

Location.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOCATION")
public class Location {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    ...

}
```

Company2Locations.java

```
@Entity
@IdClass(Company2LocationsId.class)
@Table(name = "COMPANY_2_LOCATIONS")
public class Comany2Locations {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID")
    @NotNull
    private Company company;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "LOCATION_ID")
    @NotNull
    private Location location;
    ...
}
```

Company2LocationsId.java

```
public class Company2LocationsId{

    private Company company;
    private Location location;
    ...
}
```

I want to add a separate id to the join table "Company2Locations" so the table has three columns:

- ID // Separate id
- COMPANY_ID
- LOCATION_ID

I have tryed the following to achieve this:

1. Added an ID and kept the @IdClass:

Company2Locations.java

```
@Entity
@IdClass(Company2LocationsId.class)
@Table(name = "COMPANY_2_LOCATIONS")
public class Comany2Locations {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID")
    @NotNull
    private Company company;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "LOCATION_ID")
    @NotNull
    private Location location;
    ...
}
```

This delivers a NullpointerException when i start the application.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.hibernate.internal.util.StringHelper.root(StringHelper.java:374)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getSubclassPropertyTableNumber(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1832)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.BasicEntityPropertyMapping.toColumns(BasicEntityPropertyMapping.java:46)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toColumns(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1775)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getIdentityColumns(FromElement.java:352)
```

2. Added an ID and removed the @IdClass and the @Id Annotation on the Location and Company:

Company2Locations.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANY_2_LOCATIONS")
public class Comany2Locations {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID")
    @NotNull
    private Company company;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "LOCATION_ID")
    @NotNull
    private Location location;
    ...
}
```

Now the application starts and i can add locations to a company. But the ids are not generated and id column contains a null value.

Any ideas how to add a separate id to a join table?

Comment: You have to use the Comany2Locations(sp) in your model as an object inbetween Company and Location rather than have company reference Location directly. Within Company, it should be a OneToMany using a mappedby="company".

Comment: Thank you Chris. I guess that is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is the correct answer posted by chris as comment:

You have to use the Comany2Locations(sp) in your model as an object inbetween Company and Location rather than have company reference Location directly. Within Company, it should be a OneToMany using a mappedby="company"